# how can we embed iframe in email signature

Tags: php, html, iframe

i am developing a php application which fetch the employ details from DB, and display it on a pre-build template of signature,
i tried html and its working fine, but the issue is there are soo many employs so its creating mess for HR persons.
so what i am looking for instead of giving html to a user to add into its signature, i just give them iframe code like `<iframe src="https://example.com/signature.php?emp=123"></iframe>`

and it displays the signature of that employ, alternate solution is also very much appreciated

Comment: What exactly is causing the problem for HR?

Comment: to generate and attach signature to emails

Comment: Is there any way you can write a script to attach the signatures yourself? I don't know your level of access to the mail system or what kind of API, if any, it has. Failing that, do employees know their own id numbers? Could they go to a page and be presented with the HTML signature to copy/paste themselves?

Comment: ok let me elaborate lit bit more, what i am currently working on i got access to DB, now i have a webpage on which employ can come and enter employ number then click on generate Signature. signature populated in HTML. but in html any employ can change signature details. like designation, name etc, what my client want is to restrict employees for making such changes etc. i hope i cleared the point

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. I'd suggest dynamically generating a PNG of the signature and having the employees embed that as their signature - it'll automatically update with changes to the database and the only control they'd have is to not show it at all.

Comment: yeh that is also an option but issue in generating Image is, we cant all social media any other kind of link :-P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190619/discussion-between-umair-mehmood-and-frozenjakalope).

Answer (score 3):

Most mail clients block iframes in email. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/01/do-iframes-work-in-email/

Comment: Thanks buddy, but is there an alternate solution?

Comment: Yes, you can embed an external image and update the image instead. At least this way you can have the data get updated.